# SQL query select with multiple dynamic conditions from array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, select, conditional-statements

I want to perform a SELECT query with conditions which are stored in an array beforehand.
However this array will be filled dynamically depending on how many properties will be passed.

The attributes would be stored in a MySQL db like this:

```
| car_id | brand | fwd | ac | abs | gasoline | diesel |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 000001 |   VW  |  0  |  1 |  1  |     0    |    1   |
```

Then the variables would be selected through a form.

```
$4wd = isset( $_POST['fwd'] );      
$diesel = isset( $_POST['diesel'] );                
$gasoline = isset( $_POST['gasoline'] );              
$ac = isset( $_POST['ac'] );                          
$abs = isset( $_POST['abs'] );     

$features = array();

if ($4wd == true) {          
    array_push($features, "fwd");        
}     
if ($diesel == true) {                       
    array_push($featuresn, "diesel");                 
}                    
if ($gasoline == true) {                    
    array_push($features, "gasoline");                    
}                   
if ($ac == true) {                    
    array_push($features, "ac");                    
}                   
if ($abs == true) {                    
    array_push($features, "abs");                
}
```

Now here is where it I can't find an answer to my problem;
a "static" select query wouldn't work because at this point the array         $properties can have different number and typed of values:

```
$features ([0] => fwd [1] => abs [2] => ac)  
$features ([0] => fwd [1] => abs [2] => ac [3] => diesel)   
$features ([0] => abs [1] => ac  [2] => gasoline)
```

Can't figure out the actual syntax so here what I want in laymans terms:

```
SELECT car_id FROM car_list WHERE [firstarrayvalue==1] AND [secondarrayvalue==1] AND [thirdarrayvalue==1]
```

until all values of the array have been used as condition.

Comment: which sql database?

Comment: MySQL, will add that in the OP too

Comment: so basically you are after of the cars which has (1) value to any of those columns right? is that the fixed number of columns?

Comment: the cars must have (1) in all of columms which correspond to the values of the array. If only one value of the array has the value (0) in the table it will not be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest preparing all the where-clauses in an array and imploding them into the query.

```
foreach($features as $f) {
   $sqlfeatures[] = "$f = 1";
}

$sql = "SELECT car_id FROM car_list WHERE ".implode(' AND ', $sqlfeatures);
```

#### Or a simple one-liner

```
"SELECT car_id FROM car_list WHERE ".implode(' = 1 AND ', $features)." = 1";
```