# How to improve this Laravel query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

```php
$pfilters = ProductFilters
        ::whereIn('Tb_Product_filters.filter_value', $values)
        ->groupBy('Tb_Product_filters.product_id')
        ->join("Tb_Products","Tb_Products.id","Tb_Product_filters.product_id")
        ->join('Tb_Identities', 'Tb_Identities.id', '=', 'Tb_Products.employee_id')
        ->select(
            "Tb_Products.*",
            "Tb_Identities.first_name as fname",
            "Tb_Identities.last_name as lname"
        )
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
```

This query gives me all products witch in the values array , I want only the product in include all values that mean for example

if i have values = `[1,2,3]`

this above statement gives me any product has `value_id` = `1` or `2`,`3`

I only want the product collect the 3 attrs that mean only the product has `value_id` = `1` and `2` and `3`  it should search in many rows.

i have 4 tables 
products 
filters
filters_value
products_filters

first we start with filters

any filter has one or many filters_values 
example : filter = color ,  filters_value = [red,blue,green] you now the relationship between them depend on filter_id as forgen key

products table: when i create products i will choose product filter and values
example: iphone = [color:glod, rom:128GB]
so i will store them in products_filters

products_filter table will contain ; product_id , filter_id , filter_value

so let say i want products with color:red, and rom 64GB  ?

Comment: So does 'ProductFilters' have many `Tb_Product_filters`? Do you have a relationship on your model for this?

Comment: no i did't make any relationship between them

Comment: @laravelmail you say that you want the Product that has `value_id` = `1`, `2` AND `3`. How could this possible? Is `value_id` an array?

Comment: let me explain for you

Comment: i have 4 tables 
products 
filters
filters_value
products_filters




first we start with filters 

any filter has one or many filters_values 
example : filter = color ,  filters_value = [red,blue,green] you now the relationship between them depend on filter_id as forgen key 



products table: when i create products i will choose product filter and values
example: iphone = [color:glod, rom:128GB]
so i will store them in products_filters
products_filter table will contain ; product_id , filter_id , filter_value
so let say i want products with color:red, and rom 64GB  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed 
this is the answer

```
$values = explode(",", $request->input('values'));
        $organization_id = $request->input('organization_id');
        $prodicts_filters_ids = ProductFilters::whereIn('filter_value', $values)->groupBy("product_id")->select("product_id")->get()->toArray();
        $products_have_values = [];
        foreach ($prodicts_filters_ids as $pfids) {
            $filers = ProductFilters::where([["product_id", $pfids['product_id']]])->Select("filter_value")->get()->toArray();
            $all_product_filters_Values_ids = [];
            foreach ($filers as $filer) {
                $all_product_filters_Values_ids[] = $filer['filter_value'];
            }

            $any_dif = array_diff($values,$all_product_filters_Values_ids);
            if(count($any_dif)<=0){
                $products_have_values[] = $pfids['product_id'];
            }


        }

        $products = Product::where("Tb_Products.organization_id",$organization_id)->whereIn("Tb_Products.id",$products_have_values)
            ->join('Tb_Identities', 'Tb_Identities.id', '=', 'Tb_Products.employee_id')
            ->select(
                "Tb_Products.*",
                "Tb_Identities.first_name as fname",
                "Tb_Identities.last_name as lname"
            )
            ->get()->toArray();


        return $products;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$pfilters = ProductFilters::select("
SELECT 
TB_PRODUCTS.*,
Tb_Identities.first_name as fname,
Tb_Identities.last_name as lname 
FROM Tb_Product_filters 
JOIN Tb_Products ON TB_Products.id=Tb_Product_filters.product_id 
JOIN Tb_Identities ON Tb_Identities.id=TB_Products.employee_id")
WHERE (Tb_Product_filters.filter_value = '$values[0]' OR Tb_Product_filters.filter_value = '$values[1]' OR Tb_Product_filters.filter_value = '$values[2]')
```

Depending on how many values in your array, add "OR Tb_Product_filters.filter_value = $values[X]"

Comment: it's not going to wok because values length unknown it's dynamic

Comment: also your query are same like my given query

Comment: Then you'll have to create a dynamic ->whereRaw() statement and replace it with the ->whereIn(...). As far as I can see, there is no magical solution for your request. You'll have to build up the raw expression and inject the string. You may find inspiration here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43461076/sql-query-select-with-multiple-dynamic-conditions-from-array